# Communication between Skype and Skype For Business apps

Tags: skype-for-web

I enabled Skype for Business users to communicate with other Skype users. However this does not work as expected so I am not sure if we are doing it wrong or communication between these two apps does not work as we expect it.

1. When I send a message from Skype for business, I get it on my Skype Linux app, but I cannot reply. I see a message that messaging is not available.
2. When I log into Skype web app I can see the message, but as of a few days ago, I cannot reply.
3. When I log out of Skype web app and log back in, I see a message that I have to add again the Skype for business user. When I click on the add button, nothing happens and such user is seen as "not available".

Is there is a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: Yes. I have cancelled subscriptions to Skype For Business and reverted back to the regular Skype. Really! This is not a joke.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about installable applications, not web apps.